# Is it possible to position a button on top of a table layout as a layer?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have four buttons tight together to form a square, I am trying hard to figure out how to position a button over the four buttons, in the center so it basically overlaps them. Here is my current layout with the four buttons:

```
<TableRow android:layout_weight="0.2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#357ae8"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/b1tl"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/b2tr"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/b3bl"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/b4br"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Lives"
        android:textColor="#357ae8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Score"
        android:textColor="#357ae8" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#357ae8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#357ae8" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

I was thinking I could maybe use a relative layout and and try and hard code the button so it was in the center of the square of buttons, but as soon as I tried this it affected the table layout. Is it even possible to do this sort of thing in Android layouts?

Comment: Try using a `FrameLayout` instead.

Comment: you can use a linear layout and set the orientation to vertical and have a button before the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi It is possible using FrameLayout. Here is the completed code where a button is centrally positioned between two buttons in a row. Similarly you can solve to position a button centrally among all the four buttons. Here is how I did it: In a table row> A FrameLayout. Inside the FrameLayout A LinearLayout and a Button as a Child so that they `both can overlap` (property of framelayout). By doing so whatever we place inside the LinearLayout will also be layered with the previous button.

---

Please check this code. I think this is what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#357ae8"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="-7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Center Button" />

    </FrameLayout>

</TableRow>


<TableRow
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Lives"
        android:textColor="#357ae8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Score"
        android:textColor="#357ae8" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#357ae8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#357ae8" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is excellent thank you, I am experimenting with it now, but when I try to position if in the center of the four buttons it affects the layout of the other buttons, maybe I am doing it wrong, I will keep trying! Thank you! :)

Comment: How should the code be to position it between the four buttons without affecting the layout? Thanks!

Comment: If you didn't do already: I can think of it as: In a row take a Framelayout and a button so they both overlap. Inside the framelayout take a Horizontal linear layout. The first child in that Horizontal linear layout will be another vertical linear layout with two child. The second child of the Horizontal linera layout will be another vertical linear layout with two more child. And thus you can place the initial button on center of these elements. Hope you get it, otherwise let me know.

Comment: I still have not been able to do it, but I will keep trying, thank you for your help!!! :)

Comment: I think I have tried everything, I cannot get this layout at all, I thin it impossible, here is what I am aiming for: http://www.game-center-achievements.com/buttons.png   Thank you!!

Comment: hi, sorry for the delay. i thought it was easy for you to solve. please check the new code.

Comment: Thanks for your help and for showing me how to do this, I just could not figure it out :( but now I am happy I have the solution eventually! Thanks a lot for your continued help on this question!

Comment: my pleasure, keep exploring!

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something, but...

What if you put your current layout INSIDE a `RelativeLayout`, aligning it to top, bottom, left & right.

Confirm nothing changes, and it still works right.

Then place a button inside this `RelativeLayout`, and align it to center inside this `RelativeLayout`.

I don't have my Eclipse handy to check this, but it should be that simple, shouldn't it?

---

i.e. very much what @durgomgiri said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16505945/383414).

Comment: yes you are right, it works and it is what nikmin did. in my code there is framelayout but they both looks same.